# ¿Cómo puedo pintar mis datos de una tabla, según si cumplen una condición?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un datatable que me muestra mi información, pero necesito que los que dicen "comprar: (numero)" se pinten siempre de rojo, he probado varias cosas pero solo he logrado que se pinte una, y la idea es que pinten todas las que esten por debajo del valor de la columna minimo. Aqui adjunto una capture de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si miran detenidamente veran que solo me ha pintado una pero necesito que pinte las demas. Aqui adjunto mi codigo donde lleno la tabla.

```
returnedData["insumos"].forEach(function(insumos){

          let stock_ceibos = insumos["stock_ceibos"];
          let stock_sambo = insumos["stock_sambo"];
          let alert_ceibos;
          let alert_sambo;

          if(stock_ceibos < insumos["minimo"]){
              alert_ceibos = "Comprar: " + (parseFloat(insumos["minimo"]) - parseFloat(insumos["stock_ceibos"]));

          }else if(stock_ceibos >= insumos["minimo"]){
              alert_ceibos = "Cantidad suficiente";
          }
          if(stock_sambo < insumos["minimo"]){
              alert_sambo = "Comprar: " + (parseFloat(insumos["minimo"]) - parseFloat(insumos["stock_sambo"]));
          }else if(stock_sambo >= insumos["minimo"]){
              alert_sambo = "Cantidad suficiente";
          }

          if(stock_ceibos == null || stock_ceibos == 0){
              stock_ceibos = "Sin Stock";
          }else if(stock_sambo == null || stock_sambo == 0){
              stock_sambo = "Sin Stock";
          }else{
              stock_ceibos = insumos["stock_ceibos"];
              stock_sambo = insumos["stock_sambo"];
          }

          $("#tableInsumos").append("<tr><td>" + insumos["nombre"] + "</td><td>" + stock_sambo + "</td><td>" + alert_sambo +"</td><td>" + stock_ceibos + "</td><td id='alert_ceibos'>" + alert_ceibos + "</td><td>" + insumos["mls"] +"ml.</td><td>" + insumos["minimo"] + "</td><td>" + "<a onclick='editarRegistro(" + '"E","' + insumos['nombre'] + '","' + insumos['id_insumo'] + '"' + ")' class='btn btn-accion btn-circle asignar' title='Editar'><i class='icon-pencil' style='color:white;'></i></a><a onclick='borrarRegistro(" + '"D","' + insumos['id_insumo'] + '"' + ")' class='btn btn-accion btn-circle asignar' title='Eliminar'><i class='icon-trash' style='color:white;'></i></a>" + "</td></tr>");

          if(stock_ceibos < insumos["minimo"]){
              document.getElementById("alert_ceibos").style.color = 'red';  
          }else if(stock_ceibos >= insumos["minimo"]){
              alert_ceibos = "Cantidad suficiente";
          }

      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En HTML los Id deben ser únicos en todo el DOM, es decir, que no puede haber más de un elemento con el mismo Id, si lo hay el navegador sólo actuará sobre uno. En tu caso estás asignando el mismo Id a todos los elementos de la columna "Por comprar".

Una solución es usar `class` en vez de `id` o poner los estilos directamente. Algo así:

```
returnedData["insumos"].forEach(function(insumos){

    let stock_ceibos = insumos["stock_ceibos"];
    let stock_sambo = insumos["stock_sambo"];
    let alert_ceibos;
    let alert_sambo;
    let alert_style;

    // Si se cumple la condición, poner el estilo en la variable alert_style, sino borrar la variable
    if(stock_ceibos < insumos["minimo"]){
        alert_ceibos = "Comprar: " + (parseFloat(insumos["minimo"]) - parseFloat(insumos["stock_ceibos"]));
        alert_style = "color: red";
    }else if(stock_ceibos >= insumos["minimo"]){
        alert_ceibos = "Cantidad suficiente";
        alert_style = "";
    }
    if(stock_sambo < insumos["minimo"]){
        alert_sambo = "Comprar: " + (parseFloat(insumos["minimo"]) - parseFloat(insumos["stock_sambo"]));
      }else if(stock_sambo >= insumos["minimo"]){
        alert_sambo = "Cantidad suficiente";
    }

    if(stock_ceibos == null || stock_ceibos == 0){
        stock_ceibos = "Sin Stock";
    }else if(stock_sambo == null || stock_sambo == 0){
        stock_sambo = "Sin Stock";
    }else{
        stock_ceibos = insumos["stock_ceibos"];
        stock_sambo = insumos["stock_sambo"];
    }

    $("#tableInsumos").append("<tr><td>" + insumos["nombre"] + "</td><td>" + stock_sambo + "</td><td>" + alert_sambo +"</td><td>" + stock_ceibos + "</td><td style='" + alert_style + "'>" + alert_ceibos + "</td><td>" + insumos["mls"] +"ml.</td><td>" + insumos["minimo"] + "</td><td>" + "<a onclick='editarRegistro(" + '"E","' + insumos['nombre'] + '","' + insumos['id_insumo'] + '"' + ")' class='btn btn-accion btn-circle asignar' title='Editar'><i class='icon-pencil' style='color:white;'></i></a><a onclick='borrarRegistro(" + '"D","' + insumos['id_insumo'] + '"' + ")' class='btn btn-accion btn-circle asignar' title='Eliminar'><i class='icon-trash' style='color:white;'></i></a>" + "</td></tr>");

});
```

Además moví el código que hace la validación y agregué una variable.

Comment: Gracias ya probe pero no funciona :(

Comment: Recién vi que la variable que estabas evaluando al final, ya fue reemplazada por otro valor, ahí edité mi respuesta.

Comment: Ahi si funciono :) muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es por la validación que estas haciendo, por ejemplo por lo que pude ver en tu codigo, la parte donde pintas la columna por comprar lo estas validando con la columna minimo (lo que acabo de decir es super obvio )
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero decir es que tu validación no esta considerando el minimo como tal, que quiero decir que en el siguiente fragmento del codigo

```
 if(stock_ceibos < insumos["minimo"]){
              document.getElementById("alert_ceibos").style.color = 'red';  
          }else if(stock_ceibos >= insumos["minimo"]){
              alert_ceibos = "Cantidad suficiente";
          }
```

estas validando que el stock sea menor a insumo minimo, para el caso que comentas,
9 es menor a 9? no es igual por ende no lo "pinta" por lo que tu validación deberia ser que fuera menor o igual (si quieres que lo pinte ) de todos manera dependera de las reglas de negocio y los requerimiento solicitado,

espero te sirva

Comment: Alli simplemente estoy verificando que el stock sea mayor al minimo, si es igual no debe pintarse, solo pinta cuando "stock (local)" sea menor al minimo, pero ahora que me mostraste eso..veo que esta funcionando mal ya que el comprar sale igual en ambos, eso lo voy a correguir pero lo que necesito es eso, que me pinte siempre que el stock este por debajo del minimo

Comment: entonces, has la corrección que comentas y te pintara, al menos con la validación que tienes y con el caso que lo planteas no lo hace por lo que te comento

Comment: Ya edite el codigo y muestra correctamente, pero sigue solo pintando 1